# append attributes to input element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

If I have input element rendered like this

```
<input id="Requester_Value" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input valid" type="text" value="" name="Requester.Value" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">
```

how can I using jquery add attributes to this input element

```
data-val-required="The Requested value field is required." data-val-number="The field Requester must be a string."
```

Comment: You can use `data()`, just make sure you do it *before* you instantiate the plugin which reads those properties.

Comment: Do you need to add *attributes* or to associate some `data-` with the element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: `data` won't add `data-*` attributes. That's a common misconception.

Comment: I'm aware of that - I would hope the plugin uses `data()` to read the attributes instead of using `attr()` and calling the DOM again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I can't see any reason to guess that it would. I certainly wouldn't, unless I needed `data`'s other features, and even then I'd be leery. Reading the attribute directly means not having the two get out of sync.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry to ask for explanation i just want to have clarification as i believe it would i even commented above now i removed it

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Requester.Value, new { @class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input valid"})` and putting the `[RequiredAttribute]` on your property?

Comment: @guradio: `data` manages jQuery's data cache, not `data-*` attributes. jQuery will initialize the data cache from `data-*` attributes, but using `data` as a *setter* does not set the attribute; setting the attribute once you've read the data via `data` doesn't update `data`'s copy of it. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vukxk5e9/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that is how i always picture it. when you `set it using data` you `get it using data` when `you set using attr` you `get it using attr` looks like this needs more clarification as to how it really behaves. with the given fiddle i cant differentiate the two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add an attribute to an element try.

```
$('#Requester').attr("data-val-required","The Requested value field is required.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.attr()` to get set attribute value:

```
$('#Requester').attr({'data-val-required':'The Requested value field is required.' ,'data-val-number':'The field Requester must be a string.'});
```

`.attr()` with `data-*` will set the data property as well as attribute value for that element. whereas `.data()` will only set data property internally and values wont be reflected in attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#Requester_Value").attr("data-val-required","The Requested value field is required.");
$("#Requester_Value").attr("data-val-number","The field Requester must be a string.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .attr() to set an attribute of an element, see the jQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
    $('#Requester_Value').attr("data-val-required","The Requested value field is required.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to add this data to input then put your input in container such div and use this method

```
var $div = $('div');

var spltInp = $div.html().split(' ');

var i = Math.floor(spltInp.length / 3);

var srt = spltInp.splice(i, 0, 'data-val-required="The Requested value field is required." data-val-number="The field Requester must be a string." ');

var newHtm = spltInp.join(' ');

$div.append(newHtm).children().eq(0).remove();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2roc4ka/

First `split()` html inside the `div` (input) then, use some number between array length (i) to avoid putting attr outside the input , and use this number as starting point to index the attr by `splice()`, finally convert the array to string by `join()`and `append` it to your div then remove the old one.

**note** : avoid using multi classes if you going to use this trick cause it may lead to syntax error and instead put those classes in another container like section and style it or avoid using this one.