# Get attribute value from input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get attribute value of each input field.

```
<input type="text" id="qty" data-id="{{$item->rowid}}" value="{{$item->qty}}">

function goUpdateCart(){

    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){

        alert($('input[type=text]').getAttribute("data-id"));
    })
}
```

My function can't work correctly

Comment: `$(this).data('id')`

Comment: `$('input[type=text]').attr("data-id")` or `$(this).attr("data-id")`

Comment: `this.getAttribute("data-id")` OR `$(this).data('id')` OR `$(this).attr('data-id')`

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738331/append-attributes-to-input-element-using-jquery?noredirect=1#comment61059500_36738331) - as stated by  T.J. Crowder `data manages jQuery's data cache, not data-* attributes. jQuery will initialize the data cache from data-* attributes, but using data as a setter does not set the attribute; setting the attribute once you've read the data via data doesn't update data's copy of it. Example: `  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vukxk5e9)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `.getAttribute("data-id");` isn't jquery method.
You can use any of the following to get the `data-* attr`:

```
$(this).data('id');
$(this).attr('data-id');
$(this).prop('dataset').id;
this.dataset.id;
```

So it could be any of the above one:

```
function goUpdateCart(){

    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){

        alert(this.dataset.id);
    })
}
```

Comment: Why not simple `this.dataset.id` instead of  `$(this).prop('dataset').id;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
     alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use each iteration element context`this` in each function to target current element along with `.attr('data-id')` or `.data('id')`:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

Comment: @C0dekid.php: what answer? already posted answer before me is incorrect. it is getting id and not data-id.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" id="qty" data-id="{{$item->rowid}}" value="{{$item->qty}}">
function goUpdateCart()
{

   var attribute=$('#qty').attr('data-id');
   alert(attribute);
}
```